# 64/72 bit SECDED ECC

Tags: error-correction

I would like to know if parity/syndrome generation for 64/72 bit SEC_DED coding is standardized or de-facto method used. I am going through some papers and all seem to have different combinations to generate the check bits.

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard but the de facto method used is described here:

https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp383.pdf

or here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ms-Lnm1wJ48

The latter explains how it maps to DRAM (which uses 64/72b coding) though once you understand the general concept you can easily adapt it to any number of bits.

Answer (score 1):

A variety of different H-matrices are used. The original paper, which gives a method of calculating them, is I believe from M. Y. Hsiao - A Class of Optimal Minimum Odd-weight column SEC-DEC Codes: [https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~culler/cs252-s02/papers/hsiao70.pdf](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eculler/cs252-s02/papers/hsiao70.pdf)

Different matrices will have slightly different probabilities of miss correcting triple errors or detecting quadruple errors. See Table 2.